# After assigning value to int pointer using sscanf, pointer triggers segmentation fault in printf

Tags: c, pointers, segmentation-fault

I have the code below, where I try to assign a value to an int pointer using sscanf, usually simple.  However, here when I assign it and try to run the following code, it first prints whatever number it gets from input, then triggers a seg fault when it's asked to print the actual pointer.  Why is this happening when the pointer isn't null?

```
int *key = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int));

if (key == NULL) {

  fprintf(stderr, "could not allocate memory for key\n");

  exit(2);

}

sscanf(line, "%i", key);

printf("key: %i\n", *key);

printf("key: %ls\n", key);
```

Output looks like this:

key: 1234

Segmentation fault (core dumped)

Comment: `int != wchar_t`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `%ls` format specifier is for printing long-character strings, not pointers.  Since `key` points to an `int` and not a null terminated array of `wchar_t`, you invoke [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) which in this case manifests as a crash.

To print the value of a pointer, use `%p`.

```
printf("key: %p\n", (void *)key);
```

Note that this is one of the few cases where a cast to `void *` is required.

Comment: Why is the cast in this case necessary?

Comment: @Pablo It's part of the definition of `%p`.  It explicitly expects a `void *`.

Comment: Oh I see. When I do `char *key = "hallo";printf("key: %p\n", (void *)key);printf("key: %p\n", key);` I get the same values. I compiled it with `-Wall` (and other `-W...`) I don't even get a warning. Why is that?